# Blender 2.81 with Nvidia Quadro 2000m

Tags: gpu, opengl

I recently installed Blender - the latest update.
Never before used this software.

I have a relative old PC, HP 8560w with a quadro 2000m graphic card.
My first problem was an error with "no open GL" support. 
I found latest nvidia drivers which supports my GPU (but they are no directly for that graphic card I have) and Blender started just well with no problems!

Then I go to GPU support tab and under CUDA I have no nvidia option to chose. I installed Blender 2.79 just to check and Yes I can chose my quadro 2000m over there.

As I understand my GPU has no support for CUDA which is required for latest blender so propably no way to render on GPU with Blender 2.80 for me.

So I have a few questions. I can't even properly model a simple house right now, but I need to know...

**1) Blender 2.81 doesnt support CUDA on my nvidia rendering, but my GPU is overall seen by app (helpfull for advanced models and texturing)? 
I mean I only lack GPU power in cycles rendering?**

**2) Can i export my models (with textures) back to 2.79 just to render with GPU on cycles?**

Comment: Welcome BEB! Just a note that hardware questions are generally off-topic for this Q&A site, not least of all because they are not easily reproducable by others.  Also questions should be singular, it would be helpful if you could rephrase your question into a singular on-topic one if possible.

Answer (score 0):

My computer also does not support openGL. When I try to open Blender 2.80 or higher, I get an error "support for openGL 3.3 or higher required". Since I am using an Intel HD graphics 3000 chipset that can not be re-programmed to run openGL 3.3, I resulted to two solutions. 1) Only use Blender 2.79, or 2) Buy a new computer. And since I am only 12 years old with a limited budget, I decided to choose option one. In your case though, you can get a decent desktop with a good GPU and an intel i9 cpu plus 16gb of RAM for around 800$

Comment: Hi Nate, thanks for Your respond. Thats very cool that as a Young man You chose to learn Blender instead play video games.

My Nvidia Quadro 2000m GPU is very old indeed, but it is supporting OpenGL 3.3. Drivers were the issue and now, not support for rendering is unpleasant.

But Your answer gives me a hope. I also have HD3000 as a "backup" GPU with my CPU, If I can run Blender, that's means in fact that Blender is using my quadro ancient GPU to run it :). So thank You for Your answer.

Comment: Yes that is probably the case. The Intel chipset is actually part of the CPU, so if there is another GPU with upgraded supports, then the operating system will default to that. Interestingly, though, HD 3000 DOES support openGL 3.3 on Linux and ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my old Dell.
I changed driver to 372.95-quadro-grid-desktop-notebook-win10-64bit-international-whql
(new features version) and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I am here on a Dell Precision M4800 Laptop with a Quadro 1100m.
Linux uses NVIDIA 418 driver right now. All working fine out of the box. (GPU rendering of course too)
Performance Improvment with GPU is 30%! Although it has only 2Gb mem. So worth trying to get it going.